# Construct mp4 file from audio buffer and video buffer C++ Windows

Tags: c++, audio, video, ffmpeg

Currently I am receiving video stream(H264 encoded buffer) and audio stream(PCMU encoded buffer) from remote end from which I can decode and render these as audio and video. Now I want to provide some APIs like -

```
string fileName = "dir/dir2/..../rec.mp4";
startRecord()
stopRecord()
```

User can start recording from any time and stop recording and the video & audio stream will be written as combined mp4 file. I can use `ffmpeg` by which I can merge a `.h264` and `.wav` file as `.mp4` file. But I want to do it programmatically directly from streams(not .h264 or .wav file) using any library or write my own. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31221606/1162233) for details. However, `mp4` doesn't support G.711 PCM mu-law encoded data, either `avi` or `mov` can be used or trans-code the data from pcm to aac will work.